# Nesting scroll views

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, interface-builder

"It just works", or does it?
So I was going nuts trying to fit [one ScrollView into another](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3528454/StackOverflow/output3.png).

I get to the point when **I actually made two separate xib files, did a scrollable label in one, and a scrollable image in another. Both are works perfectly in separate xib's.**

After that I manage to open xib files as simple text(looks like they are formatted as XML or something similar) and simply cut scrollable image view(with all of superviews that I needed) into my main.(containing scrollable label)

So the idea was simple yet beautiful, I was like 90 percent sure it is going to work, because I inserted all the necessary view-scrollView-contentView stuff. [And it is not.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3528454/StackOverflow/output3.png) As you can see guys, image is big enough, views setted to be large and you can barely see tiny bit of it. So it SHOULD be scrollable, right?

**Label with text keeps scrolling just fine, but the image wont move.**

I was also trying to get scroll enabled via code, setting property to YES, but it wont help.
I also tried disabling auto-layout, thinking that it could be easier, but it was not much luck on the first attempt. Will be great to hear you guys thoughts, maybe I should disable auto-layout and try it out the old-way? Or is there a way to solve this puzzle as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my question was a bit long and not much of a readable, sorry for that guys, anyway I found my answer and will post a solution for any of you guys wondering about the same thing.

Just a reminder, I was trying to achive scrollable text+ scrollable image. Text should be scrolled up/down and the image should be scrolled in all directions.

So I find my previous attempt almost completely broken and started fresh(couple of times) and in the end I find [the configuration](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3528454/StackOverflow/IB-nested-scrollView-solution.png) that suits my needs.

Matter of fact, this particular configuration works almost exactly out of the box, most of the trick is get the right views in position. After that you just have to add missing constraints from the "Editor"->"Resolve layout issues" menu and get rid of few nonsense constraints that IB add god know why.(like those ones that adds 200pt blank space at the bottom or so)
After that you'll be pretty much set. If not, refer to the picture link, or [github repo](https://github.com/Fenkins/Products). Hope that will help someone.